# really easy "new line" java question

Tags: java

Really simple question:

I'm trying to get a time stamp to print out on the next line of this code. it is printing to a jTextArea. How I have the code right now is not working for some reason:

```
try {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = new     java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("message");
        doc.appendChild(root);
        root.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(userName.getText() + ": " + msgText.getText() + "\n" + "sent at " + currentTimestamp));
        TransformerFactory fact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = fact.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult sResult = new StreamResult(out);
        trans.transform(source, sResult);
        msgText.setText("");
        out.println("\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: What isn't working?  How is `currentTimestamp` initalized?  Need more context in your code to help.

Comment: Why is there no code in the catch block?

Comment: Why `java.sql.Timestamp` and not just `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: It's for a class project so they don't care about error handling.

Comment: Is that better than java.sql.Timestamp? I'm new to java so I just googled timestamp java.

Comment: The only place I see where you're setting the text in a possible text area is here `msgText.setText("");`.

Comment: OH GUYS you're right, this is creating the doc to turn into XML. I guess I'll just add the timestamp on the other side when after i convert the xml into a string again.

Comment: That's not a really simple question, nor any kind of question for that matter.

Comment: To be, or not to be... that is not a question. And neither is this.

Answer (score 0):

GUYS you're right, this is creating the doc to turn into XML. I guess I'll just add the timestamp on the other side after i convert the xml into a string again